# How can I skip the intro sequence on the console version of Lego Star Wars: The Force Awakens?

Tags: lego-star-wars-the-force-awakens

*Lego Star Wars: The Force Awakens* has an unusually lengthy intro sequence (with videos for Traveller's Tales, Lucasfilm, etc.) that plays when I start the game, and I'm forced to watch the whole thing every time. I'm playing on a PS4, and I've tried all the buttons I can think of that other games use to skip cutscenes (options, face buttons, touchpad), but to no avail. Is there any way to skip the intro sequence on consoles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sadly not, at least not on the PS4 version. I've tried every button, but nothing works. It's a shame that the intro is so long AND unskippable.

Comment: As I feared. Thanks for confirming :/